# Should I use classification or regression model to predict discrete/ordinal movie ratings?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, ordinal-data

I’m making a ML model that predicts movie ratings from 1-10 (discrete). With scikit, is it better to use a classification model with 10 classes or a regression model that predicts a continuous variable that I can round to the nearest whole number? I like that the regression model takes into account the ordinal nature of the rating.

Is a regression model the better choice? My data is left-skewed with more high ratings than low ones. What are good metrics to check my model’s performance?

Comment: Why not try both and compare their performance using standard model fit statistics like cross-validated mean squared error or classification accuracy?

Comment: Good question.. how much data do you have to train with?  I agree with Noah, try both. May be classification but the problem of skewing makes it an imbalanced classification problem, so you will have to take care of that. If you are going for classification, then go for accuracy with confusion matrix as metric. If you are going for regression, go for RMSE, MAPE etc for evaluation of model performance.

Answer (score 2):

**ORDINAL REGRESSION EXISTS!**

You realize that there are issues with using classical regression or classification approaches in this situation with and ordinal outcome. Fortunately, you do not have to shoehorn your problem into such models, because there is ordinal regression!

A major proponent of ordinal regression is Frank Harrell, who has much discussion of ordinal modeling in his [*Regression Modeling Strategies*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319194240) textbook. Reading the pertinent sections there (he has related notes on his [website](https://hbiostat.org/rms/)) could be a place to start. His blog also has some posts about ordinal regression, such as [this one](https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/).